# Elliptical orbit simulation

Tags: differential-equations

I want to plot the full orbit ellipse.

```
lagrangian = 1/2 (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2) + 1/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2]; 
eq = 
  Table[ D[lagrangian, x1] - D[D[lagrangian, D[x1, t]], t] == 0, {x1, {x[t], y[t]}}]; 
sol = 
  NDSolve[
    Join[eq, {x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}], 
    {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 5}]; 

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: change `5` in the last line to `2Pi`?

Comment: Please, describe the problem you have.

Comment: And you might want to note that you've simultaneously posted this at http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1504520.  Simultaneous posting is not necessarily a bad thing but if you don't let folks know at both sites, then the unknown comments and answers at the other site will cause folks to waste their valuable time.

Comment: Where did you get your equations from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lagrangian = 1/2 (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2) + 1/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2];
eq = Table[
   D[lagrangian, x1] - D[D[lagrangian, D[x1, t]], t] == 
    0, {x1, {x[t], y[t]}}];
sol = NDSolve[
   Join[eq, {x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}], {x[t], 
    y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. First[sol]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thank you Alex Trounev..

Comment: @Leonia You're welcome!